# How can we use this nodejs TDlib to send a picture?

Tags: node.js, api, nodes, telegram

From https://github.com/Bannerets/tdl
we can send text as:

```
await client.invoke({
  _: 'sendMessage',
  chat_id: 123456789,
  input_message_content: {
    _: 'inputMessageText',
    text: {
      _: 'formattedText',
      text: ''
    }
  }
})
```

have try:

```
await client.invoke({
'': "sendMessage",
chat_id: user_id,
disable_notification: false,
from_background: true,
input_message_content: {
'': "inputMessagePhoto",
photo: {
'_': "inputFileRemote",
id: 
}
})
```

with note from https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1input_message_photo.html
without success,
seem like we need to upload the file, then get the id, but don't know how to do that,
Any suggestions? Thank you.

```
await client.invoke({
'': "sendMessage",
chat_id: user_id,
disable_notification: false,
from_background: true,
input_message_content: {
'': "inputMessagePhoto",
photo: {
'_': "inputFileRemote",
id: 
}
})
```

Using this nodejs TDlib to send photo.

Comment: Are you able to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

You need set content. On iOS it's look like.

```
.inputMessagePhoto(InputMessagePhoto(
                addedStickerFileIds: [],
                caption: FormattedText(
                    entities: [],
                    text: messageText
                ),
                height: 400,
                photo: .inputFileLocal(
                    .init(path: photoPath!)
                ),
                thumbnail: InputThumbnail(
                    height: 400,
                    thumbnail: .inputFileLocal(.init(
                        path: photoPath!)
                    ), width: 400
                ),
                ttl: 0,
                width: 400
            ))
```

`photoPath` in the example is string of local path for the file